# Difference between Votes, PostFeedback and PostNotices

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I was curious to know the database schema for the public data dump and came across [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) thread. Does anyone know the difference between the following tables:

- Votes
- PostFeedback
- PostNotices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Votes**

This table contains, well, votes. Of various types. You can see the types of votes by hovering over the VoteTypeId link on that page to view the popup with further information. Think of stuff like upvotes, downvotes, and accepts (plus other extraneous stuff).

**PostFeedback**

When a user isn't logged in or doesn't have enough reputation to cast an upvote or downvote, we record anonymous feedback for that event. This table simply contains that anonymous feedback. Only attempted upvotes and downvotes are actually stored here - no other type of vote will ever appear.

**PostNotices**

These actually only even relate to votes insofar as a user placing a bounty onto a question creates a post notice for the duration of the bounty. They are also placed by moderators, who can manually add a selection of notices to a post. A post notice is also automatically applied for a selection of lock reasons. They're essentially short messages that appear in a box directly below the post - to bring attention to a certain issue.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. Totally clear now. I think you meant "ever" not "even" in "These actually only even relate to votes".